# Private license and Apache License Version 2.0 in one commercial product?

Tags: apache-2.0, commercial

If I’m using an official cordova plugin licensed under Apache License Version 2.0 in my commercial product, am I allowed to sell it (the source code of my product to another party) under two different licenses (my license + Apache v 2.0 license)?

For instance, I developed and designed a mobile app which uses Camera and Contacts plugins both licensed under Apache License Version 2.0. However, I did not modify the code of any of the said plugins, so it's not a derivative work according to Apache License:

> For the purposes of this License, Derivative Works shall not include works that remain separable from, or merely link (or bind by name) to the interfaces of, the Work and Derivative Works thereof.

In other words, I'm building a wrapper around the plugins, but I don't interefere in their original code. I know that the license allows me to even sell such a plugin without modifications as long as I do it under the Apache License Version 2.0.

I also know that I could modify the source code of the plugin and then sell these modifications under my own license, but I'd still have to provide license and attribution for the original code that hasn't been altered.

> You may add Your own copyright statement to Your modifications and may provide additional or different license terms and conditions for use, reproduction, or distribution of Your modifications, or for any such Derivative Works as a whole, provided Your use, reproduction, and distribution of the Work otherwise complies with the conditions stated in this License.

What I'd like to know is if I'm allowed to sell the product where one license would refer to the code that's completely separable from the cordova plugins that would be subjected to the Apache License Version 2.0.

Comment: All Open Source / Free Software licences allow sale. They are not non-commercial. They are non proprietary. If they are copy-left then they will insist that you pass on the freedoms that you have to whoever you pass the software (no matter the price). If they are permissive, then you can do what you want (though sometimes have to cite the authors in your copyright notice).

Answer (score 3):

The Apache license is a permissive license and is considered commercial friendly. It allows you to include the code in a commercial product without having to release your code or the changes you make to the Apache licensed code, though it is encouraged and considered polite to share any changes you do make.

It sounds like you are correct in that your project is not a derivative work of the project, but you are still bundling the project with your distribution so you still need to give attribution within your documentation.

Comment: All Open Source and Free Software may be sold.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes, but the question isn't just about selling it, it is about selling Apache code bundled with his code that isn't under an open license.